# I got the not found error when using Optional.of in junit mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to implement a simple test in junit mockito to fetch a record from database.
This is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AddressControllerTest {



    @Mock
    AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    AddressServiceImpl addressServiceImpl;


    @Test
    void findByIdTest(){
        Address myAddress = new Address();
        when(addressRepository.findById(12)).thenReturn(Optional.of(myAddress));

        Address theAddress = addressServiceImpl.findById(12);
        assertNotNull(theAddress);
    }
}
```

But i got this error message:
"no suitable method found for thenReturn(java.util.Optional<com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.entity.Address>)"

If i remove "Optional.of" and use only the object, I didn't get any errors.

My questions are:

- why did I get that error?
- What does Optional.of really do?.In another word what's the difference in using or not using Optional.of?
  I asked second question because I couldn't see the result of using Optional.of.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
            <java.version>1.11</java.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
            <junit-platform.version>5.7.0</junit-platform.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why did I get that error?

You are trying to mock `addressRepository.findById(12)` here. When `addressRepository.findById(12)` is called, you are saying that it should return `Optional.of(myAddress)`. The thing is, it can't possibly return `Optional.of(myAddress)`, which is an `Optional<Address>`. `findById` seems to be declared to return `Address`, not `Optional<Address>`.

When you remove `Optional.of`, you are telling it to return just `myAddress`, which it certainly can do. `myAddress` is of type `Address`, and `findById` is declared to return an `Address`.

In terms of the types involved, `when` accepts a `T` and returns an `OngoingStubbing<T>`, which has a method called `thenReturn`, which takes a `T`. Since you passed an `Address` into `when`, `T` is inferred to be `Address`, and so `thenReturn` takes an `Address` too.

> what's the difference in using or not using Optional.of?

As you have seen, using `Optional.of` gives you an error, while not using it doesn't. It doesn't make sense to use `Optional.of` here, unless `findById` is declared to return `Optional<Address>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your configuration, I mount a similar test and have a correct response. Can you share your configuration?

[image]

#### AddressRepository

```java
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Integer> {

}
```

#### AddressServiceImpl

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService {

    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
    
    public Address findById(final Integer id) {
        return addressRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

}
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

#### Trie to use:

```java
when(addressRepository.findById(Mockito.eq(12))).thenReturn(Optional.of(myAddress));
```

#### Instead:

```java
when(addressRepository.findById(12)).thenReturn(Optional.of(myAddress));
```

Comment: Thanks . I added pom.xml to my question but I don't think that's a config issue becuse when I use the any() instead of "12" as the requested id, Every thing runs well.

Comment: trie to use Mockito.eq(12) instead 12 in when implementation (I already add example in this comment).